# Typescript : Object is possibly null

Tags: typescript

How to avoid Object is possibly null in VSCode though code runs ok

```
  let url = 'https://test.com/test/varstring/stringtoextract?id=test3'
  let regex = /https:\/\/test.com\/test\/varstring\/.+\/(.+)?.+/
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure, use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!`:

```
alert(match![1]);
```

Of course, an `if` statement would also do the trick:

```
if (match) {
    alert(match[1]);
}
```